# Visual Basic -- Please look through my code?

Tags: vb.net

The assignment is to add, subtract, multiply and divide huge numbers.

The first task is to figure out the add and subtract because the teacher then wants us to call the add and subtract procedures for multiply and divide.

I have messed with it, but we moved too quick through the array lecture and it just doesn't make sense to me. I was hoping someone could look over my add code and give me some suggestions.

The number entered will be 31 characters long.

Here's my code:

```
 Const Max As Integer = 30 
 Const Zero As String = "0000000000000000000000000000000" 
 Const One As String = "0000000000000000000000000000001" 
 Private Big1(Max), Big2(Max), Result(Max) 


 Private Sub BigAdd(ByVal Big1Str As String, ByVal Big2Str As String, ByRef SumStr As String) 

  Dim x, y, z As Integer 
  Dim One, Two, Sum As Integer 

  Big1Str.Substring(0, Max) 
  Big2Str.Substring(0, Max) 

  For x = Max To 0 Step -1 
    Integer.TryParse(Big1Str.Substring(x, 1), One) 
  Next 

  For y = Max To 0 Step -1 
    Integer.TryParse(Big2Str.Substring(y, 1), Two) 
  Next 

  For z = Max To 1 Step -1 
    SumStr = One + Two 
    If (Sum > 9) Then 
      Sum = Sum - 10 
      ' How to add 1 to the next place??? 
    End If 
  Next 

  ResultText.Text = SumStr 

 End Sub
```

I think I'm doing it completely wrong :( hopefully someone here can help me fix it! 
 Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: those X and Y For loops arent doing anything; the arrays are not Typed, the Z loop is not using the input vars, just adding One and Two (`One` is declared as a CONST **and** a string var); I dont quite see what you are after.  One and Zero are strings, so are you trying to add the numeric value from each character (moving the Y and Z logic into one loop might be what you are after)?  Look up TryParse - it probably doesnt do what you think.

Comment: The tryparse sections are the only things I know I did right because the teacher told us we'd need to do that.

Comment: The task is to have large integers entered by the user. then those numbers [31 characters long] are put into an array so that each character is within it's own index. Then we're supposed to add the two long numbers to get a result... but that would be adding the first index 0 with the second index 0 to get a result index 0... I really don't understand how it's supposed to work.

Comment: What result are you expecting and what problem are you running into?

Comment: Oh. One and Two are guesses... I don't know what to put in there...

Comment: I need it to add... and it isn't adding hahahah I think I'm missing huge chunks of code, but I just can't seem to understand it. The arrays are throwing me off. (My teacher rushed through the array lectures.)

Comment: Still, look up what TryParse does.  Also, you arent using the arrays (and dont need them, really). Strings **are** arrays - character arrays - which is what your code is examining with `Substring(x, 1)`.  If these are decimal values entered (base 10 - example looks like it could be binary) then the Z loop needs to consider that each "slot" is a power of ten greater than the last (10, 100, 1000 etc).

Answer (score 0):

He he... probably not allowed... but why reinvent the wheel when you will probably just make a bunch of mistakes anyway?

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.add(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Probably have to add a reference to the System.Numerics assembly

```
Imports System.Numerics

Dim x as BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse(Big1Str )
Dim y as BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse(Big2Str )
Dim result as BigInteger = BigInteger.Add( x, y )
SumStr = result.ToString()
```

Comment: That was my first idea as well, but I think it probably misses the point of the exercise.

Comment: :) yeah.. should definitely use reflector or resharper to find the BigInteger source code and use that ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I don't recognize any of that! Hahaha I think my teacher is having us go the round-about-way so that we only use the basic stuff we've been taught...

Comment: That is probably the intention.  That is why you read the question carefully, and if it just says "write a program to..." then you use my method and let him tell the next guys "no using the BigInteger class" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, since nobody else has offered, here's an option that does it the hard way.  Note that this code doesn't assume a maximum length of input, so feel free to throw thousand-digit numbers at it.  It doesn't support negative numbers, nor does it check for non-digit inputs, leading or trailing spaces, or any of the other crud that might be in a string.

```
Module NumericStrings

    Private Function BigAdd(ByVal big1Str As String, ByVal big2Str As String) As String

        'The result can be as large as the larger input, plus one digit if it carries.
        Dim maxSize = Math.Max(big1Str.Length, big2Str.Length) + 1
        Dim result(0 To maxSize - 1) As Char

        Dim place As Integer
        Dim placesOccupied As Integer = 1

        Dim digitCarry As Integer = 0

        For place = 1 To maxSize
            'Extract the digits at the specified place, treating nonexistent as zero.
            Dim digit1 As Integer = 0
            If place <= big1Str.Length Then digit1 = Asc(big1Str.Chars(big1Str.Length - place)) - Asc("0")
            Dim digit2 As Integer = 0
            If place <= big2Str.Length Then digit2 = Asc(big2Str.Chars(big2Str.Length - place)) - Asc("0")

            'Add, including the carry from the previous place.
            Dim digitSum As Integer
            digitSum = digit1 + digit2 + digitCarry

            'Take note of places occupied, so leading zeros can be excluded from results.
            If digitSum > 0 Then placesOccupied = place

            'Handle the carry out to the next place.
            If digitSum > 9 Then
                digitSum = digitSum - 10
                digitCarry = 1
            Else
                digitCarry = 0
            End If

            'Turn the resulting sum digit into a character and place it into the array.
            result(maxSize - place) = Chr(digitSum + Asc("0"))
        Next

        'Create a string from the array, excluding leading zeros.
        Return New String(result, maxSize - placesOccupied, placesOccupied)
    End Function

    'A quick demonstration.
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(BigAdd("1", "1")) 'prints "2"
        Console.WriteLine(BigAdd("8", "4")) 'prints "12"
        Console.WriteLine(BigAdd("007", "9")) 'prints "16"
        Console.WriteLine(BigAdd("99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999", "1")) 'guess :)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points.  Using a lookup table eliminates a lot of repetitious parsing to integer.  Also your code should have validation capabilities.  Strings of different lengths should be addressed as well:

```
Const digits As String = "0123456789"
Private Function BigAdd(ByVal Big1Str As String, ByVal Big2Str As String) As String
    Dim temp As String = ""
    If Not IsNumeric(Big1Str) OrElse Not IsNumeric(Big2Str) Then
        Return "Invalid string"
    End If
    Dim max, min As String
    If Big1Str.Length < Big2Str.Length Then
        max = Big2Str
        min = Big1Str
    Else
        max = Big1Str
        min = Big2Str
    End If
    Dim lendiff As Integer = max.Length - min.Length
    Dim carryover As Integer = 0
    Dim temp1 As Integer = 0
    For I = min.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        temp1 = digits.IndexOf(min(I)) + digits.IndexOf(max((lendiff) + I)) + carryover
        temp = temp.Insert(0, (temp1 Mod 10).ToString)
        carryover = temp1 \ 10
    Next
    Dim tempI = lendiff
    While carryover = 1
        If tempI = 0 Then
            temp = temp.Insert(0, "1")
            carryover = 0
        Else
            temp1 = ((digits.IndexOf(max(tempI - 1)) + carryover))
            temp = temp.Insert(0, (temp1 Mod 10).ToString)
            carryover = temp1 \ 10
            tempI -= 1
        End If

    End While
    temp = temp.Insert(0, max.Substring(0, tempI))
    Return temp.Trim("0"c)
End Function
```

You can gain several orders of efficiency by using a Dictionary(Of Char, Integer) for the lookup table instead of a string and building the final output with a stringbuilder is much faster than rebuilding a string.

Comment: Inserting a character at the beginning of a `StringBuilder` requires moving the valid contents of the buffer over by one place, so it's still O(n²), but better than concatenating `String` by a constant factor because it avoids reallocating on *every* insert.